# Favour composition over inheritance - always?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Should composition be favoured over inheritance as rule - in all circumstances?

I have read that inheritance is actually now being seen as an anti pattern.  My problem with that is that some relationships logically fit into inheritance i.e. is-a relationships.

But from reading lately this is seen as wrong?

What is the way to go with this?

Answer (score 0):

No, composition should not be favoured over inheritance as rule in all circumstances. You generally use them for different things and in different situations.